# Как сделать высоту td меньше его содержимого?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Таблица не дает сделать высоту td меньше высоты его содержимого. А мне нужно сделать определенную высоту и троеточие, если текст не помещается в td. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - поместить в ячейку `div`, ему задать нужные ограничения. Тогда он и не даст ячейке увеличиваться...

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #000;

}

td {
  max-width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;

}
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>lorem,lorem</td>
        <td>lorem,lorem</td>
        <td>lorem,lorem</td>
        <td>lorem,lorem</td>
        <td>lorem,lorem</td>
      </tr>
```

Можно [почитать](http://htmlbook.ru/css/text-overflow)